# WKWebView osx set background color

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

I have a `WKWebView` in my view

`@IBOutlet weak var htmlWKWebView: WKWebView!`

I want to change background color to red. I tried:

```
htmlWKWebView.wantsLayer = true
htmlWKWebView.layer?.masksToBounds = true
htmlWKWebView.layer?.isOpaque = false
htmlWKWebView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
```

Nothing worked. Only this:

`htmlWKWebView.setValue(false, forKey: "drawsBackground")` made background transparent. But background color not set

Answer (score 1):

How about using `webView.setValue(false, forKey: "drawsBackground")` and set color on the view underneath the webview? Use something like: `bgColorView.setValue(myBGColor, forKey: "backgroundColor")`